# I am having trouble evaluating the height in c#, when i introduce a number smaller than 1.5 still says come in

Tags: c#, string, if-statement, floating-point

```
using System;

namespace Tarea_C_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Write your age: ");
            int age = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (age >= 18){
                Console.Write("Write your height: ");
                float height = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (height > 1.5 ){
                    Console.WriteLine("Come in");
                }

                else{
                    Console.WriteLine("Stay out");
                }

            }
            else{
                Console.Write("Stay out");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. What **exactly** is your input?

Comment: Either put a breakpoint after the parse or just print the height. I suspect the parsing doesn't work like what you're expecting without explicit format https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Single_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_

Comment: I mean if i introduce for exmple a height of 1.3 stills says come in

Comment: What is your system decimal separator? Is it `,`

Comment: No sir, it is a dot

Comment: @MiguelRosales What happens if you type in `1,3` instead?

Comment: Nop it does not but im trying with decimals

Comment: @MiguelRosales Please make this your first line of code in Main()...

`Console.WriteLine(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator); // (you can do the same for NumberGroupSeparator)`

The character that is output is what is being used as the "decimal point" (even if it is a comma;-).